# Show scene once after lunching the game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

***Hello!***
I'm making a game and I want to add a tutorial(walkthrough) at the beginning of the game. 
So, I created a scene where I have all the information and now I just want to show it once after the game was launched and never show it again.

I have already search on the internet for the information. I only found some info about [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) and I don't really know how to use it.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: All I can think of is to have a settings file variable and set it to false or something once the player has launched a new game or sets it back to true..

Comment: PlayerPrefs shouldn't be used for that though

Comment: Rather write to a file in the persistentDataPath

Answer (score 1):

You can set variable in PlayerPrefs like this:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("IsFirstRun", 1);
```

and then you can check if the variable exists:

```
if(PleyerPrefs.HasKey("IsFirstRun")) // show the scene
```

This is how your script would look:

```
void Start()
{
     if(!PleyerPrefs.HasKey("IsFirstRun"))
     {
     // open scene
     PlayerPrefs.SetInt("IsFirstRun", 1);
     }
}
```

Comment: I will check and come back to you. Thanks

Comment: PlayerPrefs shouldn't really be used for something like this though .. they are ment to be for preferences like music volume, not for storing essential values.

Comment: Default PlayerPrefs is not secure at all. Use [this](https://github.com/mlnv/EnergySuite/blob/master/EnergySuite/Assets/EnergySuite/ZFrame/ZPlayerPrefs.cs) instead

Comment: @A_Kz Could you please explain a little more?

Comment: @derHugo I don't think that this is an essential value. In a worst-case scenario, if someone edits it they would have to sit through the tutorial twice.

Comment: Unity's default PlayerPrefs stores key values as plain XML. So anyone can change it. @derHugo is right. security is not a big deal in this case, but it's preferable to maximize security in any possible way. Anyway, Simply add the provided script to your project, include it in other scripts and use it in the exact way that you use Default PlayerPrefs.

Comment: @Superblar well it depends a lot ofcourse how many logic does depend on the value .. if you e.g. install an update, the PlayerPrefs get lost but in case it is the first run you also reset a lot of stuff to the default values e.g. after the tutorial ends, it would be a very huge impact on the user experience ;)